# upload and process excel file in vue

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js, xlsx

Am trying to upload an **xlsx** excel file and process it in my Vue app. But it's failing, throwing an error. Which makes me think that I'm not using or importing the library correctly since in a node projects works fine.

Am using the **xlsx** library.

#### Code

*template*

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="file" @change="onChange" />
  </div>
</template>
```

*script*

```js
import XLSX from "xlsx"

export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      this.file = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : null;
      let workbook = XLSX.readFile(this.file);
      console.log('workbook1');
      console.log(workbook);
      console.log('SheetNames');
      console.log(workbook.SheetNames);
    },
  }
};
```

At this point even being pointed to the a correct library if there is one would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is my codesandbox of the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-montalcini-w3qhy?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set up a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) first then read the file as a binary string so you can pass it to XLSX.

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      this.file = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : null;
      if (this.file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e) => {
          /* Parse data */
          const bstr = e.target.result;
          const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
          /* Get first worksheet */
          const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
          const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
          /* Convert array of arrays */
          const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 });
        }

        reader.readAsBinaryString(this.file);
      }
    },
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I did it through `read-excel-file` npm package.
Here is my code.

```
<template>
...
<input type="file" @change="onFileChange" />
...
</template>
import readXlsxFile from 'read-excel-file'
export default {
...
methods: {
  onFileChange(event) {
    let xlsxfile = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : null;
    readXlsxFile(xlsxfile).then((rows) => {
      console.log("rows:", rows)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NODE ONLY! Attempts to read filename and parse !
you can use another library of vuejs

Comment: Not really https://stackoverflow.com/a/65277787/4698790

Answer (score 0):

import it ->

import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

Comment: You may want to ellaborate on that answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).